# WebAPIで取得したデータを自分のデータベースへ格納して、次回からそこへアクセスしてデータを取得してもよいですか？

Tags: webapi

Q1.WebAPIで取得したデータを自分のデータベースへ格納して、次回からそこへアクセスしてデータを取得してもよいですか？
・この辺りのルールは、APIごとに異なるのですか？
・この辺りのルールを探す際は、どういうキーワードで探せばよいですか？

Q2.例えば、[国立国会図書館サーチAPI](https://iss.ndl.go.jp/information/api/)の場合は、どうですか？
・自分のデータベースへ格納して、次回からそこへアクセスしてデータを取得してもよい
・毎回、APIへアクセスしてデータ取得が必要
・上記以外

Comment: 「よい」とは法的に？利用規約的に？ライセンス的に？マナー的に？常識として？

Comment: 「利用規約的に」もしくは「ライセンス的に」の意味で質問しました。「法的に」「マナー的に」「常識として」についても興味はあります……。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WebAPI を使うこと（＝アクセスすること、スクレイピングすること）と
WebAPI が返してきた結果（＝単なる HTML であろう）を使うこととは
全く別物なので厳に区別してください。

前者つまり WebAPI 自体の利用規約やライセンスは WebAPI の提供元が決めるものなので stackoverflow で第三者に訊いても無意味です。当該事業者に直接訊いてください。

後者つまり得られた結果は著作権法的にいう「私的利用」の範囲であればいくらでも再利用してください。その時の便宜のために一時的に「保存」することは WebUA が普通に行っていますし私的利用のための複製（３０条）に該当するわけで問題ないです。

後者の利用が、私的利用の範囲を超える場合には著作権的配慮が必要です。許諾をもらうとか（有料かもしれないです）一定形式を守ればよい [Creative Commons](https://creativecommons.jp/licenses/) とか、その辺は元ネタのライセンス次第。リンク先、国会図書館サーチAPIの解説のリンク先にもこの辺のライセンスの話が書いてあります。

後者 [取得結果の著作権的配慮] とは別に、営利目的であれば前者 WebAPI 自体の利用申請・許可が必要な場合があります。国立図書館 API にはそう書かれています。

まあ「過去に保存した結果」は最新でないわけで、常に最新が欲しければ毎回アクセスが必要そうです。オイラのこの回答を読むには stackoverflow に再度アクセスしないといけないのと同じこと。

以上は法曹でない一般人の個人的意見にすぎません。私的利用の範囲の定義、あるいは私的利用を超える場合の扱いについて疑義があるなら専門家と相談してください。